# Opencart twig files doesnt change

Tags: twig, opencart

I'm using opencart 3.0.2 and when i change twig files it doesn't appear on site for example there is a code like this:

```
<div class="compare">
<button type="button" title="{{ button_compare }}" onclick="compare.add('{{ product.product_id }}');"<span>{{ button_compare }}</span></button>
</div>
```

and I delete this code from file but it doesn't make any change on the site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCart .twig file not showing changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46290730/opencart-twig-file-not-showing-changes)

Comment: I don't know opencart. However I could imagine you don't delete the related template caches?

Comment: I turned off the caching and deleted all caches but it didn't even work

Comment: Have you refreshed modification in OC admin and deleted cache (blue gear icon)?

Comment: how to refresh modification

Comment: Twig cache cleaning https://stackoverflow.com/a/61524855/3187127

Comment: Admin dashboard find Extensions/Modifications click blue refresh button right upper corner